# Fetching a json response from an api - react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Hi**,
 I'm currently trying to fetch a jwt-token from a response from my api.

The response looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "Auth successful",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6IlRvbUB0b20uZGUiLCJ1c2VySWQiOiI1ZGZiZTdiMWI3OTZkOTU4NzBiMGM4M2MiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzkyODg1NjYsImV4cCI6MTU4MTk2Njk2Nn0.7EmFE1D7wwqysPNkMMwiiw447TZiXy3kkqsXbyF1fDc"
}
```

Now I'm trying to fetch the token out of that response in that function:

```
_signInAsync = async() => {

    if(this.state.email !== '' && this.state.password!== ''){

      fetch('http://192.168.2.60:4563/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: this.state.email,
          password: this.state.password,
        }),
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.ok){

          console.log(this.state.email);
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
        }
      })
    }
  };
```

_signInAsync function is called via a button I have created. After severel tries with different approaches I couldn't figure out the right way, so now I'm hoping for your help!

 Greetings from Berlin!

Comment: Sorry, where do you attempt to fetch the token? I don't see anywhere the token is being referenced in the code.

Comment: Also, this is already an async function, don't subject yourself to needless callback nesting with `.then()` when you can just `const response = await fetch(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyo German man!

If you want to fetch a JSON, you need to process the data you receive first. Change your fetch to look more like this:

```
 fetch('http://192.168.2.60:4563/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    }),
  })
  .then( res => res.json() )
  .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.token) // should print your token!
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
  })
```